# What notation is this? (Boolean/Logic Function)

Tags: multiplexer, decoder, math-notation

I've come across these questions. What notation is being used in the 2nd and 3rd question? 
[image: Questions]

Thanks

Comment: Its a "Sigma" notion, it you want to look that up. However, its basically saying the output should be true under the following input conditions/values... Inputs listed in the F() part, value on the right.

Comment: This is called the Sigma notation. You might want to check this question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454634/sigma-notation-with-minterms

Answer (score 1):

You can look into this article about Boolean logic, SOP, POS, Minterms, and Maxterms:
[Boolean Logic - SOP Form and POS Form](http://www.electronicshub.org/boolean-logic-sop-form-pos-form/)

It depends whether you are looking for 1-minterm indices or 0-minterm indices.  In this case, it is using 1-Minterms since the output function is not looking for complement.

But in general, this notation is Sigma $$\sum$$which indicates a sum of **something**.  Here, the something is logic terms where the output is equal to 1.  You would add all those terms together.  The Maxterms in the other hand is the opposite.  You would AND the OR terms together (POS Form).